# no main manifest attribute, in jar in Intellij Idea, using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

Same thing works in my other project, but here I get an error : 
no main manifest attribute, in jar

here's my Gradle :

```
group 'com.vladdrummer.txtadventureserver'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile "com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.7.2"
}
```

Here's where manifest is :

[image]

So, it seems to be in a right place.

The manifest itself :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: TextAdventureServer
```

and the Artifact:

[image]

So, it seems to me that everything is in place, but when I build Artifact and try `java -jar txtadventureserver_main.jar` - it shows me error:

```
no main manifest attribute, in txtadventureserver_main.jar
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Are you the same Vlad that asked the question at   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715815/jar-file-doesnt-execute   and are you testing how the community responds ?

Comment: @ErwinSmout no, not the same. How does it relate to my question?

Comment: Please chack that manifest is added into your JAR. Unzip it and check manifest content. Also please check that there is new line after "Main-Class: TextAdventureServer"

Comment: no, in the jar there is no main class in the manifest. That's the problem - it should be there

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Any news ?

Comment: @RobinDupont yes, it's a weird workaround. First, you create artifact and you place it in a wrong place (java dir as Idea proposes). Then you delete Artifact and create it 2nd time with manifest in resources folder. Only now it is fine, manifest is in the artifact and you can delete wrong folder and 1st manifest. But this is sure a freaking bug.